# How to replace a variable with another based on a condition in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, stored-procedures

I have the stored procedure below hat is working fine.
I'd like, whoever, to be able to do a check to see if the dataset with YesterdayDate exists and, if not, replace *YesterdayDate* with *TodayDate*.

I was trying something like cheking if this count `select count(1) from TableName where DATASET_DATE = YesterdayDate` is 0, but I cannot find a way, assuming there is any, to add this check to the code without having to revamp or break everything else.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function DO_STUFF
(TodayDate date, YesterdayDate date)

return integer is status integer;

BEGIN 

DECLARE
  CURSOR c_stuff
  IS
    SELECT 
        <several_fields>
    FROM 
        TableName TODAY 
        LEFT JOIN TableName YESTERDAY
        ON  TODAY.KEY1 = YESTERDAY.KEY1
        WHERE TODAY.DATASET_DATE = TodayDate
        AND YESTERDAY.DATASET_DATE = YesterdayDate
    ORDER BY 
        TODAY.KEY1 ASC;
BEGIN
  FOR r_lines IN c_stuff
  LOOP
    <do_some_stuff>
  END LOOP;
END;

COMMIT;

STATUS := 0;

return status;

END
/
```

Does anyone have an idea on how this can be accomplished?

-- Edited to clarify:
I do need to use both predicates.
In the <do_some_stuff> section I'm mostly doing calculations and comparing the two datasets (Today versus yesterday) and updating some fields with the results.
What I want to accomplish here is to deal with the situation where the Yesterday process was not ran and there is no yesterday dataset, by comparing today against today and avoiding incorrect data on the results.

Comment: So is your goal to use one of the two predicates in your `where` clause but not both?

Comment: I believe I did not explain properly. I do need to use both predicates. 
In the <do_some_stuff> section I'm mostly doing calculations and comparing the two datasets and updating some fields with the results.
What I want to accomplish here is to deal with the situation where the Yesterday process was not ran and there is no yesterday dataset, by comparing today  against today and avoiding incorrect data on the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with the function. Whatever I understood from your first line of question, You can try the below code -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function DO_STUFF(TodayDate     date,
                                    YesterdayDate date)
RETURN INTEGER
IS
new_date DATE;
CNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT(*)
       INTO CNT
       FROM TableName TODAY 
       LEFT JOIN TableName YESTERDAY ON TODAY.KEY1 = YESTERDAY.KEY1
      WHERE TODAY.DATASET_DATE = TodayDate
        AND YESTERDAY.DATASET_DATE = YesterdayDate
      ORDER BY TODAY.KEY1 ASC;
     IF CNT = 0 THEN
        RETURN TodayDate;
     ELSE
        RETURN YesterdayDate;
     END IF;
EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
              RETURN '1900-01-01';
END;
```

Comment: This will return either today or tomorrow as the result of the procedure, correct? I edited my question to explain better, but I do not want to use one or the other, I need to use both. In the code I' comparing today versus yesterday and what I want is a way to set yesterday equal to today in case there is no dataset with yesterday (effectively comparing today versus today in this case). 
But this gave me a few ideas of what to do and might be very useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all without a `JOIN`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE function DO_STUFF(
  TodayDate date,
  YesterdayDate date
) return integer
IS
  CURSOR c_stuff IS
    SELECT key1,
           field1,
           field2,
           field3
    FROM   (
      SELECT key1,
             field1,
             field2,
             field3,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (
               ORDER BY CASE dataset_date WHEN YesterdayDate THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
             ) AS rnk
      FROM   TableName 
      WHERE  DATASET_DATE IN ( TodayDate, YesterdayDate )
    )
    WHERE rnk = 1
    ORDER BY KEY1 ASC;
BEGIN 
  FOR r_lines IN c_stuff
  LOOP
    <do_some_stuff>
  END LOOP;

  return 0;
END
/
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with DENSE_RANK, but I believe this do not do what I want. I don't need to use one date or the other but rather use today in place of yesterday in case there is no data with yesterday (I will always use today as the goal of the procedure is to compare today and yesterday, the goal of this "workaround" is to compare today versus today if there is no yesterday)